# How to get the scale value of VScale in Mono C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, mono, event-handling

I am new to using mono.

I am trying to simply get the value of Gtk.VScale when it gets updated.

Here is a simple program I have :

```
public VScale SetVibrator()
{
    VScale vscale = new VScale (0,255,1);

    vscale.ChangeValue += ( o, args) => 
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(this, 
            DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Info, 
            ButtonsType.Close, "Changed scale Value : " + args.ToString());
        md.Run();
        md.Destroy();
    };

    return vscale;
}
```

In my example, I am trying to use the MessageDialog as a debugging tool. I can't even find which property or method to use in args.

I have also tried to look through the documentation of mono and it gave me an error page (http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aGtk.VScale(System.Double%2cSystem.Double%2cSystem.Double)).

I don't really know where to look for answers so a bit of help would really be great.

Comment: Mono is a runtime. It's like the CLR but cross platform.
What you are asking is an implementation of a framework, but I don' know what namespace Vscale is in. Can you tell us what framework Vscale is part of?

Comment: @Blast_dan it is Gtk

Comment: I Think o should be the VScale object.

Not really sure though, the documentation is pretty poor as you have pointed out.

Comment: @Blast_dan Yes, o is pointing to the VScale object. but even so, it does not contain anything to fetch the current scale value. And to add to this, I have tried different event handlers of VScale and so far nothing is working T_T